# Hibernate org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException error

Tags: java, hibernate

I have seen a few questions about this but I am unable to derive a solution to my problem.

I have the following `PositionHistory` entity declared...

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "position_history")
@Cache (usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@AttributeOverride (name="id", column = @Column(name=PositionHistory.PRIMARY_KEY))
public class PositionHistory extends AbstractPersistable {

    public static final String PRIMARY_KEY = "s_posn_history_id";
    public static final String KEY = "positionHistory";
    public static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
    public static final String KEY_COMMENT = "comment";

    // String field length definitions
    public static final int LENGTH_COMMENTS = 1000;

    // Instance Variables
    private Date date;
    private String comment;

    @Column(name = "d_date", nullable = false)
    public Date getDate() {
    return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
    }

    @Column(name = "t_comment", length = LENGTH_COMMENTS)
    public String getComment() {
    return comment;
    }

    public void setComment(String comment) {
    this.comment = comment;
    }

    // hashCode()
    // equals()
    // toString()
}
```

And in the `PositionHistoryDaoImp` I am trying to delete some rows...

```
public void deletePositionHistory(Long positionId) {
    getSession().createQuery("delete from position_history a where a.position_id=:id")
        .setParameter("id", positionId).executeUpdate();
}
```

When I call `deletePositionHistory` I get the following error...

```
ERROR a.g.q.d.v.s.c.CommandProcessorImpl:75 - org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: position_history is not mapped
```

As you can see, the table is already mapped in the `PositionHisotry` Entity and the `PositionHistoryDaoImp` extends the entity.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Your help is very much appreciated.

Thank you.

---

`Position` Entity...

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "position")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = Position.PRIMARY_KEY))
public class Position extends AbstractPersistableEffective {
    ...
    public static final String PRIMARY_KEY = "s_posn_id";
    public static final String KEY_ID = "positionId";
    private List<PositionHistory> history = new ArrayList<PositionHistory>();

    ...

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Cascade({CascadeType.ALL, CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN})
    @JoinColumn(name = Position.PRIMARY_KEY)
    @IndexColumn(name = AbstractPersistable.INDEX_COLUMN)
    public List<PositionHistory> getHistory() {
        return history;
    }

    public void setHistory(List<PositionHistory> history) {
        this.history = history;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the table name in your query, as opposed to the entity name. Change this:

```
getSession().createQuery("delete from position_history a where a.position_id=:id")
```

To:

```
getSession().createQuery("delete from PositionHistory a where a.id =:id")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that @Perception. Now the where clause is failing as the `a.position_id` is not found. The `position_id` is a foreign key for Position with a OneToMany replationship. There is no declaration for `position_id` in PositionHistory entity as it is handled by hibernate I believe. How do I pass in the position id correctly in the where clause?

Comment: It should match the property name in your entity (as opposed to the column name in your db). I assume it's called 'positionId'.

Comment: That did not work, it gave me `org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: positionId` error. I have added the `Position` entity to the question as well. `positionId` is declared but still I get this error. Any ideas why? Thank you.

Comment: Please include in your original question, the properties and annotations for the `PositionHistory` entity.

Comment: Have included the `PositionHistory` entity code but there is no reference to `Position` in `PositionHistory`.

Comment: Ok, looks like the attribute you want to use is called `id`. See my updated answer for reference.

Comment: Thank you. Will pass in the `id` and see how it goes. But wouldn't a.id refer to `positionHistory.id` while I need to delete the history for `position.id`?. Will try it anyway. Thanks.

Comment: I got it going. Thanks for your help. Instead of deleting all of the position history in one go using the position id, i passed the position history id and deleted them one by one using your suggestion.  Cheers!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10273/discussion-between-perception-and-neo108)

Answer (score 1):

Change the hibernate.query.factory_class property in `hibernate.cfg.xml` file as show below....I hope it would help you..

```
<property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
```